# Can't POST with mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having an issue with the nodejs driver for mongo. Every time I try to post something, I get this error in my mongod.exe cmd instance:

```
2016-07-27T10:11:42.536-0700 I NETWORK  [conn5] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17132 SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL support
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. This worked last evening, and the last thing I did was test a POST and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the error:

"SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL support"

That implies that the connection string or connection params you're using is trying to connect over SSL, but the mongo server is not configured for SSL.

Comment: Well it wasn't previously either, but it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Sure, so something changed.  I can't help w/o more information.